# Is there any point to breaking the surveillance cameras?

Tags: portal-2

I believe in the original Portal there was an achievement for knocking down all the cameras. It doesn't look like there's a related achievement in Portal 2. Does knocking down the cameras have any effect (aside from nostalgia?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an achievement for removing cameras in Portal 2. I wondered the same thing. It is, however, fun to watch them burn with the lasers. I don't think there was a fun way to destroy cameras and other objects in the original Portal.

Comment: Other than the material emancipation grid and or incinerator?

Comment: Yeah but it's just walking through the grid and then disintegration. With incineration, it just disappears. Now with the lasers there's a bit of burning before an explosion for those of us who enjoy the dark pleasure of destroying turrets and cameras. Still in the middle of the game somewhere so I can't comment on any other fun destroyable objects that may lie in the levels ahead. :P

Comment: I once gathered all boxes, milk cartons and tin cans from a level to drop them down the incinerator. Then I fell down myself and died. Guess what, the items weren't destroyed.
Does that mean her pieces weren't destroyed either? You simply cannot trust anything in that game.

Answer (score 6):

It has no effect, and as far as I can tell GLaDOS never reacts to you breaking the cameras; there is a related achievement in Chapter 8 where you're challenged to break monitors, however.

Comment: I guess Glados is beyond caring about cameras at this point :)